Why Won't My Website Display Over Network Data? Works Fine When Connected To Wifi
I've created a website hosted on GoDaddy servers. It works fine on Wifi, but I can't load it when connected to mobile data. When I try to access it using T-Mobile data, I get an "Error_Connection_Timed_Out" message. I'm using an iOS device. I've attached an image of the sort of error message I'm getting.
Error Message Over Mobile data
Could this be related to the DNS settings on the GoDaddy servers? I've tried troubleshooting and adjusting settings but couldn't find a solution. Could the website's JavaScript or other code be causing this problem?
Any insights would be appreciated.
My Website

It could be related to the DNS settings as you suspected because changes to DNS settings can take time to propagate. So ensure that the DNS settings have fully propagated across all networks. You can check using some DNS lookup tool, I basically use DNSChecker and also ensure that your DNS records are correctly configured in the GoDaddy control panel
